# Grails greek encoding for 1 field

Tags: database, grails, encoding

The problem is that when i to save the data(in greek) on the server the title field data look's like this ??????????? but it must be Καλώς ορίσατε.

ControllerCode

```
@Secured(['ROLE_EDITOR'])
def saveArticle = {

    def member = springSecurityService.currentUser

    if(request.post){

        params.member = member
        def post = new Post(params)

        if(post.save())
        {
            redirect(action: "page",id: post.id)
        }
        else
        {
            return post.errors
        }

    }
    else
    {
        redirect(action: "addArticle")
    }
}
```

Post domain class

```
class Post {

   String title
   String body
   Members member
   Date created_at = new Date()


   static constraints = {}
```

}

the strange is that the field body returns correctly greek language and not like title.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but I thought it worth mentioning: if you want automatic timestamping, just create a field called `dateCreated` and Grails will do the rest. See [the documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#eventsAutoTimestamping) for more info. It appears you were trying to achieve this with your `created_at` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is jdbc:mysql://localhost/dev?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8

the ?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8 in the connection string..